# Implementing REST API: Trying to send Authentication parameters in body of HTTP Message

Tags: php, json, rest, api, authentication

I've been trying to implement a private API for a project of mine and I'm looking for some clarity on exactly what method (and even programming language) I should be using to create this implementation. The API was written in PHP, I believe.

The documentation states that I need an authentication token to make all API calls. In order to do that, I've been given a username and password, but I need to send it in "JSON in the body of the HTTP Message"

This is what the documentation states:

> All communications will be made using JSON over HTTP. This is a
>   RESTful API, meaning that it uses a combination of HTTP "verbs" (in
>   this case GET and PUT) and a URL that indicates the object(s) to be
>   fetched or acted upon. The parameters should be encoded in JSON in the
>   body of the HTTP message.

I'm using Postman to test the API and I can only figure out how to send authentication in the headers (I've tried using basic auth and even oAuth).

Can anyone help me shed some light on this? I've done a bit a research and I'm now a bit more lost. Any link to an example on how to do this or any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Postman to test the API and I can only figure out how to send authentication in the headers (I've tried using basic auth and even oAuth).

As you are using postman, in the body tab of the request, select `raw` type to be `JSON(applicatin/json)`

Then enter your username and password in the json format.

You can change the http verb near the url parameter to GET, POST, PUT, DELETE or more

> The parameters should be encoded in JSON in the body of the HTTP message.

Here is the sample request screenshot to send username and password in body parameter of request. I am using POST type of request here. You have to use the verb that the documentation states.

[image]

As stated in comment and [documentation that you shared](http://mikerodriguez.me/PD-AppointmentAPIReference-280317-1051-4.pdf), try using adding those username and password in params. Here is sample screenshot of the request in Postman.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The API states that I should use a GET method, so me using POST to get the auth token, would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, if the API states to use GET, then you have to use GET to get proper response. But you do not have body paramter in GET. All the params go in the url. Can you share the documentation text for more clarification?

Comment: Only when I use GET, I get a response from the API. {
  "code": 100,
  "type": "PARAM_MISSING",
  "msg": "Username and or password is missing"
}

Comment: I have updated the answer with GET request. Did you pass in similar way? Let me know

Comment: I am still getting a "missing" error message. I am sure that the credentials are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143088/discussion-between-iammikerodriguez-and-santosh).